# How to detect bottom of page and stop side nav from adding margin

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my sidebar hits the bottom of the page when a user is scrolling, it continues to add white space to the bottom of the page. Cannot figure out how to stop this from happening once the user hits the bottom of the page.

```
$(function() {
        var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
        var topPadding = 300;

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } 

            else {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 80
                });
            };  

        });
    });
```

Comment: This looks like a good use case for `position: sticky`.

Comment: This question is hard to answer without some kind of demo or css. Could you add a small demo the reproduces the problem? `Ctrl+M` in the stackoverflow editor lets you add a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `#sidebar` is taller than the viewport, and is causing the entire body to grow, as it extends past the bottom of the body when you scroll all the way down.

I would look into limiting the height of the sidebar programatically.